# I want to add the values of checkbox in recyclerview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

[as u all can see ,if i check to my checkbox the price should appear below,beside the makepayment button if i check more than one check box addition should be perform and same way the subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRVLQ.png)

I have done something that gives me result on click of button ..but i want the dynamic check box

Adpter class:

```
holder.payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        Buy_Data contact = (Buy_Data) cb.getTag();
        contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        carsList.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        Toast.makeText( v.getContext(),"Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                        + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Mainclass of recyclerview:

```
makepayment=(Button)findViewById(R.id.makepayment);
makepayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ArrayList<Buy_Data> stList = ((Mts_Payment_Adapter)adapter).getStudentist();
        int a=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++)
        {
            Buy_Data singleStudent = stList.get(i);
            if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true)
            {
                a = a + Integer.parseInt(singleStudent.getPrice());
            }
            else
            {}
        }
        Toast.makeText(Mts_Payment.this, "Selected Students:" + a, 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aaa);
        total.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface in your adapter

```
public interface callback {
  void itemSelected(Buy_Data contact);
}
```

Add an instance of this interface and a setter for this in the adapter.

```
Callback callback;

public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
  this.callback = callback;
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity from adapter is attached and use the adapter to set the callback,

```
adapter.setCallback(this);

@Override
void itemSelected(Buy_Data contact) {
  total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aaa);
  int totalValue = 0;
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(total.getText())) {
    String totalText = total.getText().toString();
    totalValue = Integer.parseInt(totalText);
  }
  totalValue += Integer.parseInt(contact.getPrice());
  total.setText(String.valueOf(totalValue));
}
```

Comment: which callback shud be implemented

Comment: Callback interface in adapter class